# Changing <template> tag content via jquery/js not working in edge - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, microsoft-edge

So I'm defining table rows via  tags, the problem when i try to grammatically add options to a selection in a column this works properly on chrome but not in edge.

Pseudo impl:

```js
var content = $('#myTemplate').prop('content');
$select = $(content).find('[name="myOption"]');
$select.append($("<option>").text("example"));

var $template = $($('#myTemplate').prop('content'));
var $copy = $template.clone(true);
var $tr = $('<tr>').append($copy).appendTo($('tbody'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<template id="myTemplate">
   <tr>
      <select name="myOption"></select>
   </tr>
</template>
```

With chrome, the option will be available, on edge not.
Thanks for any input anyone can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful to specify the version of Edge that you are using.

I guess you are running a version minor than 13, because [Can-I-Use reports that `template` is not supported there](https://caniuse.com/?search=template).